# Securing my ajax requests contained in jquery functions

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, security

I developed an ASP.NET MVC application, following this pattern:

```
<div class="content-header row h-100 ">
    <div >
        <button type="button" id="btnOK" >
            OK
        </button>
        <div id='ShowResults'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#btnOK').unbind('click').on('click', SaveDataInServer);
    });

    SaveDataInServer = function () {
        var data = { 'd1': 1, 'd2': 2};
        $('#ShowResults').empty();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("actionSaveData", "myController", new { area= "myArea" })',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {

                $(#ShowResults).html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

In many views, there are jquery functions that contains ajax requests, which send data to the server.
The web application manages user accounts and profiles, and the users can access to the web pages according to their profiles and privileges.

However, a user with the right privileges and control of a web browser, could open an Inspect Panel in the web browser and find those jquery funtions and ajax requests and manipulate them to send any data to the server.

How to secure those ajax requests?

The only solution I could see is to encrypt the JSON data that is sent as parameter in the ajax request.
But even so, that encryption could be seen in Inspect Panel.

Something like:

```
  var d1 = Encrypt('1');
        var d2 = Encrypt('2');
        var data = { 'd1': d1, 'd2': d2};

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("actionSaveData", "myController", new { area= "myArea" })',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {

                $(#ShowResults).html(data);
            }
        });
```

Could be that the correct solution?

Comment: Anyone could put a breakpoint in to see what you pass to `Encrypt()`.  Always validate server side everything that gets sent from client and make sure to not send sensitive data to client that you don't want exposed.

Comment: Would be it possible for you to send any example about it?

Comment: Example of what exactly?

Comment: My last question was wrong. In other words, it would be not recommended to use ajax in that way for saving data in database. Because I don't see how to validate server side when receiving ajax request. In this hypothetical scenario the user that is manipulating the ajax requests in browser has the right privileges.

Comment: Any data that the user should not be able to tamper with must be generated on the server, not accepted from the client. For instance, an e-commerce application should just send product IDs, not prices, the server must look up the prices in the DB.

Comment: Why don't you see how to validate the data on the server? You should have the user ID in session data on the server. If there are restrictions on what the user is allowed to access or insert, you check the parameters against these restrictions.

Comment: There's nothing special about AJAx when doing this. You have to do the same kind of validation with an ordinary form submission.